# How to return only the most recent date when joining two tables

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata, greatest-n-per-group

I have a list of physician NPI #'s that I need to convert into an internal customer ID #, and then use these customer ID's to check the last time they were contacted by a call center rep. To do this, I'm working with two tables, `NPI_Conversion` (`cid`, `npi`) and `Call_Center` (`call_center_cid`, `customer_name`, `call_date`). I only want to return the most recent date that a customer was contacted from the Call Center. This query gets me the data that I need, but it returns every call made to an NPI:

```
SELECT call_center_cid, cid, customer_name, caller_name, npi, call_date
FROM CALL_CENTER
LEFT JOIN NPI_CONVERSION
ON call_center_cid = cid
WHERE NPI IN ( # LIST OF RELEVANT NPI #'s)
```

I saw some other posts that used `max(date)`, so I tried using it like this:

```
SELECT call_center_cid, cid, customer_name, caller_name, npi, max(call_date) AS recent_call
FROM CALL_CENTER
LEFT JOIN NPI_CONVERSION
ON call_center_cid = cid
WHERE NPI IN ( # LIST OF RELEVANT NPI #'s)
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

But this only returns the max date per `caller_name`

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server...?

Answer (score 1):

A portable option uses a subquery for filtering:

```
select cc.*, nc.npi
from call_center cc
inner join npi_conversion nc on cc.call_center_cid = np.cid
where 
    nc.npi in (...)
    and cc.call_date = (
        select max(cc1.call_date)
        from call_center cc1
        where cc1.customer_name = cc.customer_name
    )
```

This would take advantage of an index on `call_center (customer_name, call_date)`.

Note that I changed the `left join` to an `inner join` (the filtering in the `where` clause makes it clear that's what youw ant), and prefixed all columns with the table they belong to (which makes the query much clearer about the underlying data structures).

If your database supports window functions, you can also do:

```
select cc.*, np.npi
from (
    select cc.*, 
        rank() over(partition by customer_name order by call_center_cid desc) as rn
    from call_center cc
) cc
inner join npi_conversion nc on cc.call_center_cid = np.cid
where nc.npi in (...)
```

Comment: very helpful, and a much different approach then I was thinking!  In general, would it be more efficient to get the list of NPI to CID conversions ahead in a separate query and paste them into this query to avoid having to use the JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to GMB's answer:

You can apply a ROW_NUMBER after the join to get the latest row:

```
SELECT call_center_cid, cid, customer_name, caller_name, npi, call_date
FROM CALL_CENTER
LEFT JOIN NPI_CONVERSION -- RIGHT JOIN?
ON call_center_cid = cid
WHERE NPI IN ( # LIST OF RELEVANT NPI #'s)
QUALIFY -- filter latest date per cid
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY cid
         ORDER BY call_date DESC) = 1
```

Your current WHERE turns the LEFT join into an INNER join, maybe you want a RIGHT join instead.